# How to write English and Arabic in same line without corrupting/shifting the English word visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

when i write a comment (to describe my code) in Arabic language , i mostly use English words inside my Arabic statement, i found that this English word shifted to the left most of the whole statement. How to write a whole Arabic statement with some English words in the statement without this corruption.
Code Example: 
i[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmBaR.png)am trying to write this statement: 
{
وهكذا الحال فى التعامل مع كل
node
يتم التعامل معها عن طريق ال 
header
}